# flink: applying multiple aggregations on a windowed stream

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have some data coming in as id, float, float, float. I want to min(), max() and sum() the fields in order and group this by the **id** value.

Using **flatMap** I have a **Tuple4** with the bits but I'm not sure how to send it to the next step.

What I have:

```
dataStream.flatMap(new mapper()).keyBy(0)  
   .timeWindowAll(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).min(1)  
   .timeWindowAll(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).sum(2)
   .timeWindowAll(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).sum(3)
   .map(new printstuff());
```

Is this the correct way to handle this? Or do I need to put each `timeWindowAll` in its own statement with `keyBy` and so forth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chaining of multiple aggregation functions is not supported in the DataStream API yet.

In your example, you create three distinct 5-second windows each of which applies a single aggregation. This is probably not what you want to do. I would implement a custom `ReduceFunction` that performs all aggregations at once in a single window. See *Window Reduce* in the [DataStream documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html#transformations) for an example.